# SAS How to create multiple variables with date suffix in a do loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to create multiple variables based on conditions with date as their suffix. The following code only generate one variable from the end date. How do I make it generate multiple variables based on dates in between the end and start date, and keep them on master2?

```
%macro dis_status(startdate,enddate);
%let sasstart = %sysfunc(inputn(%substr(&startdate,3,6),yymmdd6.));
%put &sasstart;
%let sasend = %sysfunc(inputn(%substr(&enddate,3,6),yymmdd6.));
%put &sasend;

%do sasdate=&sasstart %to &sasend;
    %let date= %sysfunc(putn(&sasdate,yymmdd6.));
    %put &date;

     data master2;
       set master1;
        if code22_&date. in ('1','2','3','4') 
                then status22_&date. = "G "; 
        else if CODE22_&date. in ('5','6') 
                                         then status22_&date. = "IE"; 
        else if CODE22_&date. in ('7','8') 
                then status22_&date. = "NR"; 
        else CODE22_&date. in ('10,'11')
                then status22_&date. = "UE"; 
       run;
%end;
%mend;

%dis_status(20220608,20221019);
```

Comment: What you try to achieve is most probably not clear to everyone. I would consider giving a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the macro code with in the DATA Step source to generate the statements you want.

*Data provided in a very wide layout with date representation as part of the variable name is typically problematic in the long run.  Consider pivoting the data so the date is a column.  Such a table can be processed efficiently with `WHERE`*

Wide Example:

This presumes the data set `have` has many variables named `CODE22_yymmdd` and many new variables named `status22_yymmdd` are to be computed.  Macro code is used to create source code for initializing arrays.  A custom format is used to perform the transformation from code to status.

```
* mock up some wide data;
data have;
  call streaminit(20230221);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    length code22_230101-code22_230131 code22_230201-code22_230228 $2;
    array code22 code22_:;
    do over code22;
      code22 = put(rand('integer',1,12),2.-L);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format;
  value $code_to_status (default=2)
    '1','2','3','4' = 'G '
    '5','6' = 'IE'
    '7','8' = 'NR'
    '10','11' = 'UE'
  ;
run;

%macro example(from, to);

  %local from_date to_date date yymmdd;

  %let from_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&from,yymmdd8.));
  %let to_date   = %sysfunc(inputn(&to,yymmdd8.));

  data want;
    set have;
    array code22 %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
                    %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
                    code22_&yymmdd.
                 %end;
    ;
    length %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
              %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
              status22_&yymmdd.
           %end;
    $2 ;
    array status22 %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
                     %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
                     status22_&yymmdd.
                   %end;
    ;

    do over code22;
      status22 = put(code22, $code_to_status.);
    end;
  run;

%mend;

%example(20230115,20230214);
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I posted  an extension to this question on another post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562078/sas-fill-array-with-variable-end-with-date-some-dates-are-missing Could you take a look? Thanks!