# SAS fill array with variable end with date, some dates are missing

Tags: sas, sas-macro

This code is from an answer to my previous question. [SAS How to create multiple variables with date suffix in a do loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516082/sas-how-to-create-multiple-variables-with-date-suffix-in-a-do-loop)

@Richard

In the code, array `code22` takes in values from `code22_&yymmdd.` variables, but not all `code22_&yymmdd`. exist on the dataset :

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230221);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    length code22_230101-code22_230131 code22_230201-code22_230228 $2 bwght0-bwght80 8;
    array code22 code22_:;
    array bwght22loop bwght:;
    do over code22;
      code22 = put(rand('integer',1,12),2.-L);
    end;
    do over bwght22loop;
      bwght22loop = put(rand('integer',1,12),2.-L);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format;
  value $ code_to_status (default=2)
    '1','2','3','4' = 'R '
    Other   = 'NR'
  ;
run;

%macro example(from, to);

  %local from_date to_date date yymmdd;

  %let from_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&from,yymmdd8.));
  %let to_date   = %sysfunc(inputn(&to,yymmdd8.));

  data want;
    set have;
    array code22 %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
                    %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
                    code22_&yymmdd. /*not all dates in the defined range exist*/
                 %end;
    ;
    length %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
              %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
              status22_&yymmdd.
           %end;
    $2 ;
    array status22 %do date=&from_date %to &to_date;
                     %let yymmdd = %sysfunc(putn(&date,yymmdd6.));
                     status22_&yymmdd.
                   %end;
    ;

    do over code22;
      status22 = put(code22, $code_to_status.);
    end;
  run;

%mend;


%example(20230115,20230214);
```

How to create `status22_&yymmdd.` that only take in the existing `code22_&yymmdd` varialbes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this version of the problem use data set metadata information that can be obtained from either SQL `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS`, data set view `SASHELP.VCOLUMN` or output from `Proc CONTENTS`.

Example:

Knowing plain DATA Step programming is essential before moving to writing macros or programs that generate source code.  In this example the core of the macro is this neat and simple step:

```
    data want;
      set have;

      length &stat22_variables $2 ;

      array code22 &code22_variables;
      array stat22 &stat22_variables;

      do over code22;
        stat22 = put(code22, $code_to_status.);
      end;
    run;
```

However, the complete example shows the preparation for getting to the step is filled with verifications, validations and transformations.  *If you can work with a data model that does not need all the prep work the cleaner the programming is in the long run.  All the prep is needed because the date 'data' is in the column name.*

Proc SQL is used to populate macro variables that are used in the DATA step.
*Assigning a macro variable a value through programmatic means is sometimes called 'populating' the variable.*

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230221);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    length
        code22_230101 - code22_230107
    /* Columns for Jan 8, 2023 to Jan 23, 2023 are not present */
        code22_230124 - code22_230131
        code22_230201 - code22_230228
        $2
    ;
    array code22 code22_:;
    do over code22;
      code22 = put(rand('integer',1,12),2.-L);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;


proc format;
  value $code_to_status (default=2)
    '1','2','3','4' = 'G '
    '5','6' = 'IE'
    '7','8' = 'NR'
    '10','11' = 'UE'
  ;
run;

%macro example(data=, from=, to=, out=);

  %if ^%length(&data) or ^%length(&from) or ^%length(&to) or ^%length(&out) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: (&SYSMACRONAME): At least one parameter is empty. &=data &=from &=to &=out;
    %return;
  %end;

  %local from_date to_date date yymmdd;

  %let from_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&from,yymmdd8.));
  %let to_date   = %sysfunc(inputn(&to  ,yymmdd8.));

  %if &from_date=. or &to_date=. %then %do;
    %put ERROR: (&SYSMACRONAME): One of the dates is not yymmdd8. &=from &=to;
    %return;
  %end;

  /* macro variables will be populated by Proc SQL INTO from meta data output by Proc CONTENTS */

  %local code22_variables;
  %local stat22_variables;

  /* get meta data (just the column names as data)  */
  proc contents noprint data=&data out=__columns(keep=name);
  run;

  /* process the names that meet the naming criteria and macro parameters */
  proc sql noprint;
    select name 
         , transtrn(lowcase(name),'code22','status22')
    into   :code22_variables separated by ' '
         , :stat22_variables separated by ' '
    from   __columns
    where lowcase(name) like 'code22^_%' escape '^'
      and input(substr(name,8),yymmdd6.) between &from_date and &to_date  /* date part of variable name in date range */
      and length(name) = 13
  ;

  %put NOTE: &=code22_variables;
  %put NOTE: &=stat22_variables;

  %if %length(&code22_variables) = 0 %then %do;
    /* no columns correspond to date range.  copy input to output */
    data &out; 
      set &want;
    run;
    /* or you could 
    %put ERROR: No code22 columns in &data are for &=from to &=to;
    */
  %end;
  %else %do;
    data want;
      set have;

      length &stat22_variables $2 ;

      array code22 &code22_variables;
      array stat22 &stat22_variables;

      do over code22;
        stat22 = put(code22, $code_to_status.);
      end;
    run;
  %end;
%mend;


/* TEST: */
/* the data has some columns missing for a date in the date range */
/* the date range in this macro call does not cover all the code22_yymmdd columns in the data */

%example(data=have, from=20230115, to=20230214, out=want);
```